# How to deploy a php application from local machine to google app engine

Tags: php, git, google-app-engine, upload, setup-deployment

I am new to google cloud plateform. I have a php application on my local host and want to set up this on App engine. I followed some documentation and used **gcloud deploy** command for example given in documents. It was working properly. But in examples it first clone a git repository and deploy a code from that on app engine. I know how to launch app engine instance. But I am not getting how I will upload code from my local host to app engine. I know app.yaml and config files are needed but my question is - how I will upload and deploy code to app engine even if I created app.yaml and config files.

I heard about **google app engine launcer** but didn't find any valid source for installing on ubuntu. Is there any **client software** that can be used to deploy my code on app engine or **is it compulsory to first set up my code on git** then use it as given in example in document.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [quickstart in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/quickstart). It covers everything that you need:

1. Downloading the Cloud SDK (The launcher is ancient and deprecated, don't use it.)
2. Creating a Cloud Platform project in case you haven't yet.
3. Running locally, which you've already figured out.
4. Deploying your project to App Engine using the `gcloud app deploy <path_to_app.yaml>` command.

You don't need or want the launcher. You don't need to do anything with git.

Comment: I understand step 1,2,4 but step 3 is real problem. I have installed cloud SDK but dev_appserver.py  is real problem as it is not going to start

Comment: The text of your question implies the problem is with deployment, not local testing. I suggest editing your question to accurately state the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After installing google cloud SDK and following all instruction on [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-extension) i sucessfully set up local development server and php application.